# Configuring Django to use remote mysql server?

Tags: mysql, django, configuration

I am trying configure a Django application to use mysql.

I want to use the mysql server available in my network and don't want to install a local copy.

But when I am trying to install mysqldb it needs mysql_config from Mysql!

What should I do if I want to use the mysql server in another machine?

```
sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "~/Dev/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1/setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "~/Dev/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1/setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

Tried downloading the MySQL files and pointed to "mysql_config" and built mysqldb.

But when I tried to import mysqldb I get:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/tmp/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /tmp/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Any hint on what the error is?

Thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention the platform. I am running under Mac OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got MySQLdb compiled without installing MySQL server in my MacOSX.

The steps:

1. Download appropriate MySQL package (tar) not install version and unpack
2. Download MySQLdb wrapper from [MySQL Python bindings](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/)
3. Unpack MySQLdb
4. Edit site.cfg to point to mysql_config into the directory you have downloaded
5. Follow the instructions in MySQLdb (essentially build & install)
6. Copy the file libmysqlclient_r.15.dylib from your 'mysql/lib' folder to /usr/local/mysql/lib (assuming you have choosen threadsafe version)
7. Now you are ready to use MySQLdb with any MySQL server
8. You can test the installation using: python >>> import MySQLdb

Comment: Another note for anyone who runs into this sort of thing...the number "15" in the libmysqlclient_r.15.dylib will change with the MySQL version you have installed, so if you're building from source, make sure you do so with the proper MySQL version installed (just an addendum to the "any MySQL server" part of #7). I accidentally had an issue where I built a MySQLdb .egg and it was looking for libmysqlclient_r.15.dylib, but my system only had libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib (and no, it doesn't work if you just rename it). Good question...helped me figure out my bug with MySQLdb & pyanttasks. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to install mysql's client libraries on the machine running Django so it can connect to a remote MySQL server. Both plain libmysqlclient and python's mysql driver. Further details depend on the platform you are running this on.

Comment: Thx for the info, is it possible to get MySQL client libraries along? I looked at MySQL website and found only the installer packages?

Answer (score 1):

Install a pre-compiled version of the MySQLdb driver. Most Linux distributions provide it in their repositories -- for example, in Debian and Ubuntu it's named `python-mysqldb`.

Also, as this does not involve programming, it would be best moved to Superuser.

Comment: Or to serverfault? This is more like a server configuration issue

Comment: Based on hint tried to find a precompiled version, but couldn't found one for Python 2.5 [http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/Packages]