# Django - MySQLdb: Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows

Tags: python, mysql, django

A colleague got this error message when trying to use MySQLdb from Django:

```
[...]
ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/roy/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): 
Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows 
Referenced from: /Users/roy/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg-tmp/_mysql.so Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

He's using OS X 10.5, Python 2.5 (arriving with OS X), MySQL 5.1 & MySQLdb 1.2.3c1.

Any idea how to attack this?

Answer (score 6):

It might be best if you install mysql and it's Python bindings from scratch, I use the following steps whenever I need MySQLdb on OS X 10.4 or 10.5:

1. Install [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#macosx-dmg) for your system, the dmg installer should be sufficient
2. The default location of MySQL will be somewhere around: `/usr/local/mysql-5.0.45-osx10.4-i686`.  From `/usr/local/mysql/lib`, create a soft link:

   `ln -s ../../mysql-5.0.45-osx10.4-i686/lib mysql`
3. Download the [MySQLdb source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/) and unpack it
4. Edit the file `site.cfg` under your unpacked MySQLdb directory, comment out the `registry_key` and set `mysql_config` to:

   `mysql_config = /usr/local/mysql-5.0.45-osx10.4-i686/bin/mysql_config`
5. Carry on with the regular Python packages build from within MySQLdb directory:

   `sudo python setup.py install`
6. If everything is fine above, test MySQLdb in a new terminal:

   `python -c "import MySQLdb"`

The above should return nothing if successful.  The above example shows OS 10.4 and MySQL 5.0, substitute them with the your proper tools version.

Comment: The mysql 10.6 dmg is not out yet, once it's released, give it another whirl.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It nearly worked on my system (OSX 10.7). However I need to add the **-arch x86_64** flag to the compiler and linker flags. This is how I need to change the **setup_posix.py** from the MySQLdb-python package: in the section where the `ext_options` are build I changed `extra_compile_args = extra_compile_args` to `extra_compile_args = extra_compile_args + ['-arch',"x86_64"]` and `extra_link_args = extra_link_args` to `extra_link_args = extra_link_args + ['-arch',"x86_64"]`

Answer (score 1):

It was Complicated and hard but it worked on **MacOSX Lion**.

you will be using :

```
Xcode
Brew
Port
Pip
```

make sure that you have Xcode(4.X) installed , and your mac is configured to find the executables because it will be used by **Macports** during the process of installing mysql-python.

Make sure that Xcode Command line Tools are installed

start Xcode app >> preferences >> download >> Components tab >> Command Line Tools >> click install

run the following commands from the terminal.

`xcodebuild -version`

if you ran into this **error**

`/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version Error: No developer directory found at /Developer`

Try to Run

`/usr/bin/xcode-select`
this will update the developer directory path.

Then you need to switch manually to the new Xcode install dir in /Applications:

```
sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

[Ref](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/27820)

**Uninstall** mysql [*Backup you data before doing so !*].

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
```

Use [brew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) to install Mysql again:

```
brew install mysql
```

you might run into this error.

```
Error: Cannot write to /usr/local/Cellar
```

the **[fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5112493/1340281)**.

you should be ready to go now.

```
sudo port install py27-mysql

pip install mysql-python

python -c "import MySQLdb"
```

if you don't see any errors MySQLdb is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the MySQLDb egg was compiled against a different version of libmysqlclient than the version present in the system. You need to either get a proper egg (uninstalling the previous) or to build MySQLDb from scratch to compile it against the library present in your system.

I don't know why but I think your colleague might be interested in this question:

[Configuring Django to use remote mysql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297917/configuring-django-to-use-remote-mysql-server)

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with Thierry's solution on 32-bit Python (2.6.5) on OS X 10.6.

Upgrading to Python 2.7 64-bit version fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I'm using 2.7 already, still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
easy_install -U distribute
pip install --upgrade mysql-python
```

Note:
If you have any errors of missing symbols while compiling, you need to have mysql development libs to compile it.

On Linux it's easy to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-devel
```

or:

```
sudo yum install mysql-devel
```

On Mac you probably need to download [MySQL Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/#downloads) and then you may have to pass in a --with-mysql-libs option to point to the directory when the C libraries are unpacked to. 
Or you can try to put the libraries in the default directory: /usr/lib64/mysql

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

make sure it should installed properly

or you can use another alternative like `easy_install`