# Problem using MySQLdb on OSX: symbol not found _mysql_affected_rows

Tags: python, mysql, macos

This is related to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299013/problem-using-mysqldb-symbol-not-found-mysql-affected-rows).

However, the main posted solution there is not working for me. I'm on Snow Leopard, using the 32-bit 5.1.49 MySQL dmg install. <strike>I'm using the built in python</strike> (apparently, as noted in the comments, my Python version is different), which appears to be 2.6.5 32-bit:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79359, Mar 24 2010, 01:32:55) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint
2147483647
```

I've downloaded MySQL-python 1.2.3 from [the usual location](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) and changed site.cfg so that mysql_config points to the right place and the registry_key directive is commented out. The packages seems to build and install just fine:

```
caywork:MySQL-python-1.2.3 carl$ python setup.py clean
running clean
caywork:MySQL-python-1.2.3 carl$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb
running build_ext
caywork:MySQL-python-1.2.3 carl$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
writing manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb
running build_ext
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/_mysql.so -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/_mysql_exceptions.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb/release.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/MySQLdb/times.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/_mysql_exceptions.py to _mysql_exceptions.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py to connections.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py to CLIENT.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py to CR.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py to ER.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py to FIELD_TYPE.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py to FLAG.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py to REFRESH.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/converters.py to converters.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py to cursors.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/release.py to release.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/MySQLdb/times.py to times.pyc
creating stub loader for _mysql.so
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/_mysql.py to _mysql.pyc
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/EGG-INFO
writing build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg
Removing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg
Copying MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages
MySQL-python 1.2.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg
Processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.3
Finished processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.3
```

But when I try to use it, I get this:

```
caywork:MySQL-python-1.2.3 carl$ python -c "import MySQLdb"
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg/_mysql.py:3: UserWarning: Module _mysql was already imported from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg/_mysql.pyc, but /Users/carl/Source/MySQL-python-1.2.3 is being added to sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in 
    import _mysql
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in 
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/carl/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Users/carl/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

All I can find on the web are older examples of this problem, along with numerous rants about how hard it is to get MySQL-python working on OSX. If anyone can help with this, I would greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: Note, you are not using the Apple-supplied Python 2.6 on 10.6.  That's at `/usr/bin/python` and is currently Python 2.6.1.  That one is a 64-bit/32-bit universal build.  You're most likely using the 32-bit-only Python 2.6 from the python.org installer (installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework ...) and with a link from /usr/local/bin/python2.6.

Comment: Thanks Ned! Do you think that this problem I was experiencing would have been different if I had been using the Apple-supplied Python?

Comment: +1 to allow you to add more than 1 link.  Having similar issues with MySQL using python 2.7.1 32bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only (admittedly kludgy) solution that I ended up getting to work was to use MySQL-python-1.2.2 after applying [this patch](http://gist.github.com/511466), cobbled together from advice found here (http://www.mangoorange.com/2008/08/01/installing-python-mysqldb-122-on-mac-os-x/) and here (http://flo.nigsch.com/?p=62). Sorry for the lack of links but I don't have enough rep points to post more than one link.