# Installing mcrypt extension for PHP on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: php, macos, apache, mcrypt

Apologies in advance for the potential n00b questions, I am trying to install the mcrypt extension for PHP on my OSX Mountain Lion machine.

The following steps in terminal is what I have done so far to achieve my PHP install

```
cd /path/to/downloaded/php-5.3.21/ext/mcrypt/
/usr/bin/phpize
./configure
cd /path/to/downloaded/php-5.3.21
./configure --with-config-file-path=/private/etc/php.ini --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs
make
sudo make install
```

Which seems to work well and installs PHP 5.3.21 fine. I have then done

```
sudo nano /private/etc/php.ini
```

And included

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Along with an Apache restart, phpinfo() doesn't show that the mcrypt extension is loaded.

I then tried to specify the extension_dir inside php.ini, again with no luck.

I have done

```
locate mcrypt.so
/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so
/usr/local/Cellar/php53-mcrypt/5.3.18/mcrypt.so
```

And tried both directories as the extension_dir, with no luck.

I have also tried the following, after much Googling

```
./configure --with-config-file-path=/private/etc/php.ini --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-mcrypt
```

Which seems to work OK, but then upon "make", it returns

```
ext/mcrypt/mcrypt.o: No such file or directory
ext/mcrypt/mcrypt_filter.o: No such file or directory
```

Again, no success.

What am I doing wrong? It seems like the physical compile of mcrypt.so is not happening, or is compiling incorrectly as I would suspect there to be another mcrypt.so found under locate?

Anyone please help? I've gone through pages upon pages of Google searches with no luck!

Comment: This guide worked for me: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server

Answer (score 78):

I tend to use Homebrew on Mac. It will install and configure all the stuff for you.
[Link](https://brew.sh)

Then you should be able to install it with `brew install mcrypt php53-mcrypt` and it'll Just Work (tm).

You can replace the `53` with whatever version of PHP you're using, such as `php56-mcrypt` or `php70-mcrypt`. If you're not sure, use `brew search php`.

Do also remember that if you are using the built in Mac PHP it's installed into `/usr/bin` you can see which php you are using with `which php` at the terminal and it'll return the path.

Comment: In the above brew install command `brew install mcrypt php53-mcrypt` you have `php53-mcrypt`. Does that change to `php54-mcrypt` if my php installation is PHP 5.4.11?

Comment: Yeah. I would still search for the package to make sure. `brew search mcrypt`

Comment: I used this command to install mcrypt, but homebrew cannot link it, overwriting the links is not allowed either.  Have you come across this issue?

Comment: You need [homebrew-php](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php#usage) for that

Comment: For me this required the following (php53-mcrypt was not available directly): `brew tap josegonzalez/php`, `brew tap homebrew/dupes` and then `brew install php53-mcrypt`. I found this package with `brew search php | grep mcrypt`

Comment: `brew install mcrypt php55-mcrypt` did the job

Comment: Had to run `brew tap homebrew/php` first

Comment: hieugioi-2:Cellar hieugioi$ brew install mcrypt php717-mcrypt
Error: No available formula with the name "php717-mcrypt" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.

Comment: Sadly I need this one now. can't make it work

Answer (score 50):

I just went through this on Mountain Lion.  Homebrew blocked on libiconv which it thought was missing but was actually up to date.  After an hour of trying to get it to recognize libiconv, I gave up and installed it the old fashion way, which took all of five minutes...

```
(download your php version)
$ wget http://www.php.net/get/php-5.3.21.tar.gz/from/a/mirror
$ tar -xvzf php-5.3.21.tar.gz
$ cd php-5.3.21/ext/mcrypt
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make test
$ sudo make install
```

mcrypt.so is now in your PHP ext dir (`/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/` in my case), now you need to add to php.ini as a module

```
$ vi /etc/php.ini
$ (insert) extension=mcrypt.so
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

Done - no brew necessary.  HTH someone.

Comment: I actually did use brew to install autoconf, since phpize failed without autoconf.

Comment: This may not work without first installing libmcrypt, and even then you may still have issues.

Comment: Confirmed fix for Ubuntu 13.10 with PHP 5.5.4 +

Comment: Yeah this works just match the version you already have installed. 
php -v

Comment: Simplest solution by a long, long way.

Comment: I have tried many ways and solutions but this just worked. Thanks

Comment: This is probably pilot error on my part, but just in case: That wget command line, for me, downloads a web page instead of the .bz2 file. If, instead, I visit that URL in a browser, it gives me the opportunity to pick a mirror from which to download. So I figured that was worth mentioning in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

Comment: ...Of course, then the phpize command failed with a "Cannot find autoconf" error. Oh, well.

Comment: This. I tried this after SO many other solutions and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Don't exist any more.

Comment: @JovylleBermudez some detail would be useful - like WHAT doesn't exist anymore - all of this was answered 10 years ago, so obviously things have changed....

Comment: its the http://www.php.net/get/php-5.3.21.tar.gz/from/a/mirror

Answer (score 38):

## Installing php-`mcrypt` without the use of `port` or `brew`

> *Note: these instructions are long because they intend to be thorough. The process is actually fairly straight-forward. If you're an
>   optimist, you can skip down to the **building the mcrypt extension**
>   section, but you may very well see the errors I did, telling me to
>   install `autoconf` and `libmcrypt` first.*

I have just gone through this on a fresh install of OSX 10.9. The solution which worked for me was *very* close to that of **ckm** - I am including their steps as well as my own in full, for completeness. My main goal (other than "having `mcrypt`") was to perform the installation in a way which left the least impact on the system as a whole. That means doing things manually (no `port`, no `brew`)

To do things manually, you will first need a couple of dependencies: one for building PHP modules, and another for `mcrypt` specifically. These are `autoconf` and `libmcrypt`, either of which you might have already, but neither of which you will have on a fresh install of OSX 10.9.

### autoconf

Autoconf (for lack of a better description) is used to tell not-quite-disparate, but still very different, systems how to compile things. It allows you to use the same set of basic commands to build modules on Linux as you would on OSX, for example, despite their different file-system hierarchies, etc. I used [the method described by Ares on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322742/php-autoconf-errors-on-mac-os-x-10-7-3-when-trying-to-install-pecl-extensions), which I will reproduce here for completeness. This one is very straight-forward:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/mcrypt/dependencies/autoconf
$ cd ~/mcrypt/dependencies/autoconf
$ curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz
$ tar xzf autoconf-latest.tar.gz
$ cd autoconf-*/
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Next, verify the installation by running:

```
$ which autoconf
```

which should return `/usr/local/bin/autoconf`

### libmcrypt

Next, you will need `libmcrypt`, used to provide the guts of the `mcrypt` extension (the extension itself being a provision of a PHP interface into this library). The method I used was based on the one described [here](http://michaelgracie.com/2011/07/21/plugging-mcrypt-into-php-on-mac-os-x-lion-10-7/), but I have attempted to simplify things as best I can:

First, download the `libmcrypt` source, available from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/Libmcrypt/), and available as of the time of this writing, specifically, at:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/Libmcrypt/2.5.8/libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.bz2/download

You'll need to jump through the standard SourceForge hoops to get at the real download link, but once you have it, you can pass it in to something like this:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/mcrypt/dependencies/libmcrypt
$ cd ~/mcrypt/dependencies/libmcrypt
$ curl -L -o libmcrypt.tar.bz2 '<SourceForge direct link URL>'
$ tar xjf libmcrypt.tar.bz2
$ cd libmcrypt-*/
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

The only way I know of to verify that this has worked is via the `./configure` step for the `mcrypt` extension itself (below)

### building the mcrypt extension

This is our actual goal. Hopefully the brief stint into dependency hell is over now.

First, we're going to need to get the source code for the `mcrypt` extension. This is most-readily available buried within the source code for all of PHP. So: determine what version of the PHP source code you need.

```
$ php --version # to get your PHP version
```

now, if you're lucky, your current version will be available for download from the main mirrors. If it is, you can type something like:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/mcrypt/php
$ cd ~/mcrypt/php
$ curl -L -o php-5.4.17.tar.bz2 http://www.php.net/get/php-5.4.17.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror
```

Unfortunately, my current version (5.4.17, in this case) was not available, so I needed to use the alternative/historical links at http://downloads.php.net/stas/ (also an official PHP download site). For these, you can use something like:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/mcrypt/php
$ cd ~/mcrypt/php
$ curl -LO http://downloads.php.net/stas/php-5.4.17.tar.bz2
```

Again, based on your current version.

Once you have it, (and all the dependencies, from above), you can get to the main process of actually building/installing the module.

```
$ cd ~/mcrypt/php
$ tar xjf php-*.tar.bz2
$ cd php-*/ext/mcrypt
$ phpize
$ ./configure # this is the step which fails without the above dependencies
$ make
$ make test
$ sudo make install
```

In theory, `mcrypt.so` is now in your PHP extension directory. Next, we need to tell PHP about it.

### configuring the mcrypt extension

Your `php.ini` file needs to be told to load `mcrypt`. By default in OSX 10.9, it actually has `mcrypt`-specific configuration information, but it doesn't actually activate `mcrypt` unless you tell it to.

The `php.ini` file does not, by default, exist. Instead, the file `/private/etc/php.ini.default` lists the default configuration, and can be used as a good template for creating the "true" `php.ini`, if it does not already exist.

To determine whether `php.ini` already exists, run:

```
$ ls /private/etc/php.ini
```

If there is a result, it already exists, and you should skip the next command.

To create the `php.ini` file, run:

```
$ sudo cp /private/etc/php.ini.default /private/etc/php.ini
```

Next, you need to add the line:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Somewhere in the file. I would recommend searching the file for `;extension=`, and adding it immediately prior to the first occurrence.

Once this is done, the installation and configuration is complete. You can verify that this has worked by running:

```
php -m | grep mcrypt
```

Which should output "`mcrypt`", and nothing else.

If your use of PHP relies on Apache's `httpd`, you will need to restart it before you will notice the changes on the web. You can do so via:

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

And you're done.

Comment: I truly can't believe no one bothered to thank you for this huge effort. I didn't ask the above question, but I'm definitely using your answer, and thank you very much for it.

Comment: I agree. Worked like a charm. I didn't use all of the CURL commands since it was easy to search the provided directories for the files I needed, download them manually, and unpack them manually.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory` and the same for `zend_modules.h` and `zend_extensions.h` - any ideas? (PHP 5.4.24)

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat what version of MacOSX are you running?

Comment: @Will 10.9.3. But don't worry, I went back to using homebrew and finally managed to solve the problems I was having with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, very detailed and helpful.

Comment: This tutorial is ABSOLUTELY AMAZING, thanks! 
Everything worked perfectly except for a small snag: I had to skip this line 
`code curl -o curl -o libmcrypt.tar.bz2 '<SourceForge direct link URL>'`
download that file manually and then 
`code tar xjf {DIRECTORY TO DOWNLOADED FILE}`

Comment: Wow, @AdamBubela! So many people have gone through this tutorial, I can't believe you're the first to spot that error!

That should have been: `curl -L -o libmcrypt.tar.bz2 '<SourceForge direct link URL>'`, ie: one of the `curl -o`'s in there was redundant, and it should also follow redirects (`-L`) to pick up the correct mirror.

Corrected now in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is one of best answer i ever saw on stackoverflow. I follow each step without any problem and it still works (one year later). Very impressive. Thanks for taking the time to share this tutorial.

Answer (score 10):

### Why You're Getting This Error

PHP complains if one of the files like `mcrypt.so` is included using the syntax `extension="mcrypt.so"` but the file is not in the `extension_dir` path ( use `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` or `php -i` to check that).

It will also tell you which `php.ini` config file is being loaded so you will know where the settings are coming from. Most likely it will be something like `/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini` if you are using the homebrew version.

Take note of the part under it that says something like "Scan this dir for additional .ini files" because what that means is it gives you a place to put your own file, like `tweaks.ini` that is loaded after the main configuration file so that you can make changes and keep up with them easily. Also remember that all the files in this directory get loaded in alphabetical order, so if you have one called `adjustments.ini` that contains `mcrypt` directives, and there is a `mcrypt.ini`, most likely your settings will be overridden.

One alternative to specifying `extension="mcrypt.so"` is to specify the full path to the `mcrypt.so` file. The other option is to edit the `extension_dir` setting.

### What worked for me

On Mavericks I didn't have to do either. I did a fresh install of `homebrew` and then added the josegonzalez tap using:

```
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
```

(My other laptop was running Mountain Lion and was also using homebrew in this setup.)

After you've tapped **[that awesome repo](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php)** you can install `php` and `mcrypt` using something like:

```
brew install php54 php54-mcrypt
```

### What if this doesn't work (and why should I use homebrew anyway?)

I would highly advise trying this route before downloading and building it from source. It's not hard to build from source - but I don't want to have to maintain that. It's one of the reasons to use `homebrew` in the first place - it's a package manager (with a HUGE community).

There is a lot of development on the `homebrew` project and - if you have problems I'd suggest checking out their [issues page](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/issues)

**So yes you can build it from source and that might seem like a good option right now if you just want mcrypt to work but you may hate yourself for doing this later...**

If you don't want to be using `php54` there is also the `php53` branch. They have some instructions at the repo about how to use both of them / switch between them.

If you're new to homebrew you should know that you check out what else is available using `brew search php54`, which gives something like:

```
php54                php54-lzf          php54-snappy        
php54-amqp           php54-mailparse    php54-solr          
php54-apc            php54-mcrypt       php54-ssh2          
php54-apcu           php54-memcache     php54-stats         
php54-boxwood        php54-memcached    php54-svm           
php54-chdb           php54-midgard2     php54-tidy          
php54-couchbase      php54-mongo        php54-timezonedb    
php54-dbase          php54-msgpack      php54-tokyotyrant   
php54-ev             php54-mysqlnd_ms   php54-twig          
php54-gearman        php54-oauth        php54-uploadprogress
php54-geoip          php54-opcache      php54-uuid          
php54-gmagick        php54-parsekit     php54-varnish       
php54-graphdat       php54-pcntl        php54-wbxml         
php54-http           php54-pdflib       php54-xcache        
php54-igbinary       php54-phalcon      php54-xdebug        
php54-imagick        php54-proctitle    php54-xhgui         
php54-inclued        php54-pspell       php54-xhp           
php54-intl           php54-pthreads     php54-xhprof        
php54-ioncubeloader  php54-raphf        php54-xmldiff       
php54-jsmin          php54-redis        php54-yac           
php54-judy           php54-riak         php54-yaf           
php54-leveldb        php54-runkit       php54-yaml          
php54-libevent       php54-scrypt       php54-yaz           
php54-libvirt
```

## TLDR

- You should use `homebrew` to install `mcrypt` if at all possible
- If you're getting errors it's probably because your configuration file(s) are messed up. Check the `extension_dir` path and figure out where the `mcrypt.so` file is and see if there is a discrepancy (or specify the full path)

Comment: I highly recommend following this guide: http://justinhileman.info/article/reinstalling-php-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 8):

For me, on Yosemite

```
$ brew install mcrypt php56-mcrypt
```

restart computer

did the trick.

Comment: I can run it with: brew install mcrypt

Comment: No doubt, the best solution. My "El Capitan" said... "Up you go"

Answer (score 5):

Solution with brew worked only after the following:
in your php.ini

```
nano /private/etc/php.ini
```

add this line:

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php53-mcrypt/5.3.26/mcrypt.so"
```

Warning! Set the correct PHP version.

Comment: Cellar comes from homebrew

Comment: This works perfectly. [This other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357107/installing-mcrypt-on-osx-10-8-2-php-5-3-15-with-homebrew) has pointed me in the same direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend installing everything via homebrew if you have the option. I went in circles for a while, but installing php 5.x via brew and then the neccessary modules worked a treat.  I was working with php 5.4 and used this to get going initially:

https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php

and then installed the additional modules with:

```
brew install php54-redis
brew install php54-xdebug
brew install php54-mcrypt
```

...

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility for those who want to keep OS X as clean as possible, is to use vagrant [1] to define a php development environment. Vagrant can use VirtualBox [2] in headless mode (~3% of CPU on my 13-inch, Mid 2009 MacBook Pro) to run a virtual machine with the webserver and php and all.

To easily create the vagrant environment you can use this great tool https://puphpet.com/

1. http://www.vagrantup.com/
2. https://www.virtualbox.org/

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a shell script to install mcrypt module for PHP 5.3 without homebrew.

The scripts install php autoconf if needed and compile module for your php version.

The link is here: https://gist.github.com/lucasgameiro/8730619

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked and finally got it working using resource @[Here](http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server/) and [Here](http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/install-mcrypt-php-extension-on-mac-os-x-lion/); Just remember for OSX Mavericks (10.9) should use PHP 5.4.17 or Stable PHP 5.4.22 source to compile mcrypt. [Php Source 5.4.22 here](https://www.php.net/get/php-5.4.22.tar.gz/from/a/mirror)

Answer (score 1):

**Brew base solution worked for me**

1. Install these packages

   $brew install brew install mcrypt php54-mcrypt
2. Copy default php.ini.default to php.ini

   $sudo cp /private/etc/php.ini.default /private/etc/php.ini
3. Add this line to php.ini file extension section - please verify extension path with install location in your machine

   extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.3.26/mcrypt.so"
4. Restart your apache server

   $apache restart

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

```
$ wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/Libmcrypt/2.5.8/libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz/download
$ tar xzvf libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install

$ brew install autoconf

$ wget file:///Users/rmatikolai/Downloads/php-5.4.24.tar.bz2
$ tar xjvf php-5.4.24.tar.bz2
$ cd php-5.4.24/ext/mcrypt
$ phpize
$ ./configure # this is the step which fails without the above dependencies
$ make
$ make test
$ sudo make install


$ sudo cp /private/etc/php.ini.default /private/etc/php.ini
$ sudo vi /private/etc/php.ini
```

Next, you need to add the line:

```
extension=mcrypt.so

$ sudo apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 0):

mycrypt.o and mcrypt_filter.o are in the ext/.libs of your php downloaded directory. Just copy the files to ext/mcrypt, then run make && make install again.

Answer (score 0):

With recent changes in brew (deprecation of homebrew/php) you now install php with mcrypt with the following.

```
brew install php@5.6 -with-mcrypt=mcrypt
```

You may have to uninstall previous installs of php

Answer (score 0):

So after running `brew install mcrypt php`, I had to install php-mcrypt via pecl:

`pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1`

At the time of writing, mcrypt does not have a stable pecl release, 1.0.1 being the current release for php 7.2 and 7.3, and `brew install php` will install php 7.2.

Answer (score -4):

> sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
>
> ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/mcrypt.ini
>
> service php5-fpm restart
>
> service nginx restart