# How do I link mcrypt?

Tags: php, magento, terminal, mcrypt

I am trying to install mcrypt for use on my local machines dev environment.  I need to this to install Magento.

I used this answer to [install mcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595841/installing-mcrypt-extension-for-php-on-osx-mountain-lion), but get the following error:

```
$ brew link mcrypt
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.5.8... Warning: Could not link mcrypt. Unlinking...

Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.5.8/include/mutils/mcrypt.h
Target /usr/local/include/mutils/mcrypt.h already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and delete this file, do:
  brew link --overwrite formula_name

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
```

Trying to overwrite the links as suggested in not allowed.

```
$ brew link --overwrite mcrypt
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.5.8... Warning: Could not link mcrypt. Unlinking...

Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/include/mutils/mcrypt.h
```

Prepending this command with "sudo" does not fix this issue as that is also not allowed.

Running `php -m` doesn't show mcrypt as an installed module, and also throws the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

This all seems to be related to the fact that I cannot link this, I just can't seem to solve this issue though.  Has anyone encountered this? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: What linux distributions are you using and did you try to install as `root` user?

Comment: @R.S — the `brew` command indicates he's using `homebrew`, which indicates he's using OS X.

Comment: Yes, I am using OS X mountain lion.  Sorry I failed to mention this from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thomas, from what I can see above it looks like you're trying to use Homebrew to install the `mcrypt` package to your **system**, but `mcrypt` has already been installed by another package management system (or may ship by default in your version of OS X — I don't keep up on these things)

Since mcrypt is already installed on your ***nix** system, what you need to do is install the **PHP extension** for mycrypt, or install a version of PHP that support mcrypt out of the box.

My usual approch to this is to use the [hp-osx.liip.ch](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) package (which seems to be the successor to Marc Liyanage's old `entropy.ch` package).  This installs a stand alone version of PHP as a binary, and should have the libraries you need to run Magento.

Comment: I was under the impression that `brew install mcrypt php53-mcrypt` installed the php extension - do you know if this is correct?  If that is correct than I already have the extension installed and just need to link, but have been unable to do so.

Comment: @thomas I'm more a `ports` person, and this stuff is an endless cascade of permutations, but hopefully this helps: The command `brew install mcrypt` installs `mycrypt`.  The command `brew install php53-mcrypt` installs PHP 5.3 with the mycrypt extension. The command `brew install mcrypt php53-mcrypt` installs `mcrypt`, and then installs PHP 5.3 with the mcrypt extension. Homebrew won't create the symlink to mcrypt because **there's already an mcrypt** in /usr/local from something else.  Having homebrew blow this away would probably be a bad idea. It sounds like all you need is PHP with mcrypt.

Comment: @Thomas your getting the PHP error because its failing to load the extension :) I had the same problem. If you run the locate command. E.g. locate mcrypt.so it will show where it is located. Then presuming you are using the stock PHP edit /etc/php.ini find the mcrypt line and replace the paths. Failing that on my Mac I run vagrant with a true LAMP stack for magento development and it works alot better.

Answer (score 3):

I actually just ran into this problem for the second time. Couldn't remember how I solved it the first time. What worked for me this time was I actually deleted the mcrypt.h file under mutils. Then when I ran `brew link --overwrite mcrypt` it successfully linked. Then I ran `brew install php53-mcrypt` and that seemed to do the trick. Also restart the server.

Wouldn't be surprised if this doesn't work for everyone but it worked for me.