# Install PHP MCrypt for CLI

Tags: php, macos, cron, laravel-4, mamp

Setting up a CRON job for a Laravel 4 application and I've ran into a roadblock. The CRON is working, but it's returning a "Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension" error to the CRON log file I have set up.

Here is my CRON job which executes an Artisan command every minute:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /Users/Tim/Dropbox/orbis/artisan orbis:clear-players > /Users/Tim/cron.log
```

This command runs if I cd into the Laravel project folder (/Users/Tim/Dropbox/orbis), but the MCrypt isn't being detected for the CRON.

I read that sometimes the CLI uses a different php.ini file and that MCrypt may not be enabled for the CLI specifically. How can I get MCrypt installed for the CLI as well?

Not sure how relevant this is, but I've added the following to my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin:$PATH
```

Does that mean the CLI should be using the same PHP configuration file etc as MAMP?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but my knowledge is limited for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cron indicates the PHP path you are using is the OS X install of PHP in `/usr/bin/php`:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /Users/Tim/Dropbox/orbis/artisan orbis:clear-players > /Users/Tim/cron.log
```

But your export path shows the MAMP PHP install path which implies `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/php`:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin:$PATH
```

So pretty sure that is not relevant… But maybe it can help you all things considered… Read on to understand.

Basically `mcrypt` is not a part of the OS X install of PHP. There are guides & discussions on how to handle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595841/installing-mcrypt-extension-for-php-on-osx-mountain-lion) and [here](http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server/). In general, the base OS X install of PHP is never up to par.  It’s for part of that reason tools like MAMP exist. You can basically go nuts compiling it from source on your OS X install. Which can work, but yeah. MAMP.

But that said, if you have MAMP installed, you could modify your cron to use the MAMP install of PHP which should have `mcrypt` installed. Check the `phpinfo()` in MAMP from the browser & do a search for `mcrypt` to confirm.

If so, just change your cron to use MAMP’s PHP instead like so:

```
* * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/php /Users/Tim/Dropbox/orbis/artisan orbis:clear-players > /Users/Tim/cron.log
```

And it should work.

Comment: Awesome. I changed my CRON so I was using MAMP's version of PHP and it all seems to be working now. Thank you!