# How to enable mcrypt in php on Mac OSX 10.9?

Tags: php, macos, mcrypt

Since I want to start learning Laravel, I need to install mcrypt in php. I'm on Mac OSX 10.9 and I installed apache and php manually (no mamp or anything like it) so I followed [this guide](http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-development-server/) to install mcrypt. The whole procedure works as expected (no errors), but after restarting the server using `sudo apachectl restart` I have a look at the output of phpinfo(), and I can't find any mentioning of mcrypt.

Since I don't think I had any errors in the process of compiling and installing, I don't really know where to look for the mistake. Does anybody know what would be logical things to check for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing mcrypt extension for PHP on OSX Mountain Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595841/installing-mcrypt-extension-for-php-on-osx-mountain-lion)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, on MAC OS X 10.9, no mcrypt library working.
After some hours and many headaches (I'm not so skilled...) I found this guide, and finally get it working on my local machine:
http://jenssegers.be/blog/49/installing-the-php-mcrypt-extension-on-osx-10-9-mavericks

The passage I missed were to go in the ext/mcrypt dir of a new php downloaded package and then type:

cd php-5.4.17/ext/mcrypt/
/usr/bin/phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install

Then add extension=mcrypt.so in my php.ini file.

That's it.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

By default mcrypt lib is not installed on Mac OSX 10.9. So you have to first install it. You can get it from [sourcefroge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/Libmcrypt/2.5.8/libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz/download). You also need php 5.4.17 source( check your php version first `php -v`). You can get it from [github](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-5.4.17). extract both folders and.

Install autoconf

```
brew install autoconf
```

Build and install mcrypt lib

```
cd libmcrypt-2.5.8
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Build php extension

```
cd php-5.4.17/ext/mcrypt/
/usr/bin/phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Finally add extension to `php.ini`

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Restart apache `sudo apachectl restart`

[For more detailed info you can check it](http://jenssegers.be/blog/49)

Comment: Thanks, very clean and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

http://topicdesk.com/downloads/mcrypt/mcrypt-download

You can download mcrypt installer from here. It works for me!