# laravel installation failure with Composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I was following a tutorial on Lynda.com, and I am completely new to the composer/laravel scene. The tutorial told me to install the MCrypt libarary, which I did successfully from this package:

```
topicdesk.com/downloads/mcrypt/mcrypt-download
```

Composer seems to be successfully installed/running.
I then went ahead and opened terminal, and put in the following command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel first_app --prefer-dist
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

[RuntimeException]  
Error Output:      

create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] 
[--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] 
[--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] 
[--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] 
[--no-install] [package] [directory] [version]
```

Any ideas on what the issue may be? After looking around on the forums, it seems to me that it is a very case specific issue. Where do I begin in finding what may be preventing it from working correctly?

Comment: Try moving `--prefer-dist` to directly after `create-project`. Otherwise, your command looks right

Comment: @ChrisForrence I went ahead and did that, and got the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm...what operating system are you using? You may need to load it (using something like `php5enmod mcrypt`)

Comment: Given I am using OSX Yosemite on a Macbook Pro, would that be necessary?

Comment: I'm frankly not sure. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595841/installing-mcrypt-extension-for-php-on-osx-mountain-lion) might help, though