# PHP Xdebug on OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: php, xdebug, osx-mavericks

I'm having issues setting up my PHP development environment on OS X after installing OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

Here is the command I am using to install.

```
sudo pecl install xdebug

downloading xdebug-2.2.3.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-2.2.3.tgz (250,543 bytes)
.....................................................done: 250,543 bytes
66 source files, building
running: phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Anyone have a solution or a workaround?

Comment: It looks like you don't have php dev package installed

Comment: I was able to resolve the first few errors by adding symbolic links to the php libraries. However now I still need to resolve this error. Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable.

Comment: brew install autoconf

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The fast copy-paste way

```
sudo sh -c 'echo zend_extension=$(find /usr/lib/php/extensions -name "xdebug.so") >> $(php -qr "echo php_ini_loaded_file();") && apachectl restart'
```

This command do the following :

- Finds the native Xdebug extension that comes with Xcode
- Asks php which config file is loaded
- Adds the Xdebug extension path in the config file
- Restarts apache.

Compatible with Sierra, El Capitan & Yosemite with the bundeled apache, but untested with MAMP & XAMPP.

Before launching the command, make sure Xcode command line tools are installed : `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Confirmed on Mavericks although at first no php.ini file was loaded. Had to rename /etc/php.ini.default and then it worked. Thanks

Comment: @user2070775 try renaming `/etc/php.ini.default` to `/etc/php.ini`

Comment: For MAMP: uncomment xdebug in the ini file (which path you can find by watching at phpinfo() )

Comment: Runs perfectly. Make sure you have an php.ini.

Comment: Confirmed on El Capitan: make sure `/etc/php.ini` exists, and follow the [configuration instructions](http://codebugapp.com/configuration/) to add an `[xdebug]` section to the .ini file if you want to use [CodeBug](http://codebugapp.com/).

Comment: Wish I'd found this before spending 6 hours of work time trying to get this going.  My hero!

Comment: would +100 if I could

Comment: Confirmed on Sierra. Thanks!

Comment: OOOOO it had wasted my 2 hours .But your solution works like charm man, Thank you So much.

Answer (score 36):

Don't know about using `pecl`. Getting Xdebug after an OS X install is pretty straightforward without `pecl`. You've got two easy options:

1. Use the version already available at:

   ```
   /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-2010052/xdebug.so
   ```
2. Build your own:

   1. Make sure you have the Xcode CLI tools: `xcode-select --install` will prompt you to install the CLI tools. With the CLI tools installed, there should be stuff inside `/usr/include/php`.
   2. Go to http://xdebug.org/download.php and download the source tarball for the version of Xdebug you want. For example: http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.2.3.tgz.
   3. Extract the tarball and `cd` into the directory it created. Inside that directory you'll see a `README`. From here it's:

      ```
      $ phpize
      Configuring for:
      PHP Api Version:         20100412
      Zend Module Api No:      20100525
      Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
      $ ./configure --enable-xdebug
      checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
      checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
      checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
      [... output ...]
      $ make
      [... output ...]
      ```

Your built `xdebug.so` is now at `modules/xdebug.so`. The `phpize` is critical to do with XCode CLI tools installed, because `phpize` sets up the build parameters for your version of PHP.

With your `xdebug.so` in hand from (1) or (2) above, you can add this block to the `php.ini` being used by your `php` or `php-fpm`:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=<full_path_to_xdebug.so>
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=<host running PHP (e.g. localhost)>
xdebug.remote_port=<port Xdebug tries to connect to on the host running PHP (default 9000)>
```

Comment: Apart from the very minor detail of the path to the .so being /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so this worked like a charm. I took the easy way out and didn't even bother to build my own.

Comment: zend_extension not work on fresh install. Work fine, xtension. Also full path only if extension_dir it's not used. Best way it's use and put all extension there.

Comment: I get a `Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220100525.
The Zend Engine API version 220121212 which is installed, is newer.` error if I use the XCode built in `xdebug.so`. So I had to build my own for XAMPP 1.8.3-4.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Mac Yosemite 10.10 and none of the above answers solved the problem. Do the following:

1. Open a terminal
2. Execute `find /usr/lib/php/extensions -name "xdebug.so"` to know the path to the debug library.
3. Execute `sudo nano /etc/php.ini` to open and edit the php.ini file
4. In php.ini add the following lines at the end

   ```
   [XDebug]
   zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so"
   xdebug.remote_enable=1
   xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
   xdebug.remote_mode=req
   xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
   xdebug.remote_port=9000
   ```

(When finished, type `control+o` to save and `control+x` to close the file)

(Don't forget to replace the value in zend_extension for whatever you got from the first terminal command)

6. Execute `sudo apachectl restart` to load the new configuration
7. Sit back and relax

Comment: I only see `php.ini.default` and modifying it didn't change my env

Comment: @Erik did you save the configuration to `php.ini` or `php.ini.default`?

Comment: I tried both... Php.ini fixed it for a while then it stopped working in phpstorm

Comment: @Erik sorry I'm not familiar with phpstorm

Comment: After step 2 I did `sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini` (I'm on Yosemite) and then continued on to step 3. All good. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

There are two issues here. The first is that you need to install Xcode command line tools with the command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

This will mean that the files previously not found in `/usr/include/php/` will be available.

The next step is to install `autoconf` in the same way as Ares shows in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12333230/2272004).

I would `cd` into your download folder first

```
cd ~/Downloads/
curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz
tar xzf autoconf-latest.tar.gz
cd autoconf-*
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

now you can run the `pecl install` command

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Comment: I'd suggest using Brew to install autoconf rather than compiling from source- "brew install automake"

Comment: Just want to say that this step was necessary when trying to install mcrypt module by recompiling php version 5.4.17 (which comes with MacOSX Mavericks (10.9)) as per this tutorial: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-development-server/

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is facing this issue I had to build autoconf from source. I followed this answer from another StackOverflow question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12333230/2272004

Comment: Follow the instructions there present, and I pass that error, however, `1 error generated.
make: *** [xdebug.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed` - I got this one. No dice.

Comment: This may be helpful. http://remonpel.nl/2013/10/repair-osx-webdevelopment-server-after-osx-upgrade/

I did have to create soft links to a few libraries as well to build xdebug

Comment: @thank you. At the end, I found that MAMP PRO came with Xdebug. It's only a matter of uncomment a php ini line. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the issue phpize error,try this will solve your problem:
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include /usr/include

Comment: Worked for me on OS X 10.10 (I used MacOSX10.10 in the path). Thank you!

Comment: That is the real answer for this question!!! Not for `how to install xdebug on OS X 10.10`

Answer (score 2):

I had to `brew install xdebug` and choose for my version of PHP and it worked! 
For example,

```
brew install homebrew/php/php56-xdebug
```

For a PHP version 5.6 variant.