# Issues with enabling Xdebug on AMPPS

Tags: php, xdebug, ampps

I am trying to enable Xdebug on my AMPPS. I have used [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) and followed the given instructions: [image].

On a point 6 i run `make` command that compiles the xdebug library. then to check if everything went well i runned `make test`. I discover these ERRORS:

```
    Failed loading ~/Dev/Testing/xdebug-2.2.6/modules/xdebug.so:  dlopen(~/Dev/Testing/xdebug-2.2.6/modules/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found.
  Did find:
        ~wrong architecture
    Failed loading ~/Dev/Testing/xdebug-2.2.6/modules/xdebug.so:  dlopen(~/Dev/Testing/xdebug-2.2.6/modules/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found.  
Did find:
        ~/Dev/Testing/xdebug-2.2.6/modules/xdebug.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

And what did I do wrong...? and is this an ideal way of installing/enabling Xdebug anyway....? if not any turorial..?

Comment: Which platform are you using ?

Comment: pls [refer this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579401/php-xdebug-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks), I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 9):

So maybe another poor soul finds this but I solved it with changing the command `./configure` with:

`./configure --enable-xdebug CC="gcc -arch i386" CXX="g++ -arch i386"`

I'm using OS X El Capitan (10.11.5) with Ampps on PHP 5.6.Everything else stays the same as mention on the wizard.

The problem is that Ampps is 32bit and when you `make` you are compiling a 64bit version.

Comment: Man I'd give you more than one upvote if I could. Thank you very much.

Comment: How could I find my architecture? Tried it on sierra but it doesn't seems to work :(

Comment: Try with `uname -m` this gives me `x86_64` as a result. For checking the file architecture try with `lipo -info`, for example `lipo -info /Applications/AMPPS/php-7.0/lib/extensions/ext/tokenizer.so` results on `Non-fat file: /Applications/AMPPS/php-7.0/lib/extensions/ext/tokenizer.so is architecture: i386`