# Installing PECL Zip on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, zip, installation, mamp, pecl

I'd like to install PECL Zip extension for my local web server but I'm getting an annoying error:

```
Lenny-MacBook-Pro:Downloads lenny$ pecl install zip-1.12.4.tgz 
96 source files, building
WARNING: php_bin /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php appears to have a suffix /php5.5.3/bin/php, but config variable php_suffix does not match
running: phpize
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

What do I have to install to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322742/php-autoconf-errors-on-mac-os-x-10-7-3-when-trying-to-install-pecl-extensions