# PHP Imagick problems

Tags: php

So i'm trying to download the imagick dependency.  I already have the ImageMagick installed through homebrew now i'm trying to put the imagick directory in with: (i'm using mac OS)

```
sudo pecl install imagick
```

i get the following error

```
downloading imagick-3.2.0RC1.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.2.0RC1.tgz (163,503 bytes)
...................................done: 163,503 bytes
16 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Here is my current setup directory of pear

```
1. Installation base ($prefix)                   : /usr/local/pear
2. Temporary directory for processing            : /tmp/pear/install
3. Temporary directory for downloads             : /tmp/pear/install
4. Binaries directory                            : /usr/local/bin
5. PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : /usr/local/pear/share/pear
6. Documentation directory                       : /usr/local/pear/docs
7. Data directory                                : /usr/local/pear/data
8. User-modifiable configuration files directory : /usr/local/pear/cfg
9. Public Web Files directory                    : /usr/local/pear/www
10. Tests directory                               : /usr/local/pear/tests
11. Name of configuration file                    : /private/etc/pear.conf
```

Comment: brew install autoconf

see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322742/php-autoconf-errors-on-mac-os-x-10-7-3-when-trying-to-install-pecl-extensions

Comment: K so that works but now when it goes through the installation of imagick i get to:

make: *** [imagick.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed