# MAC OS El Capitan 10.11: Install XDEBUG

Tags: php, xdebug, osx-elcapitan, pecl

I am searching the way to debug php scripts. In internet i found information that i can do that with **MacGDBp** + **XDebug**.
When i'm trying install using PECL in Shell:

```
sudo pecl install xdebug

The next error have been occured:

downloading xdebug-2.4.0.tgz ...

Starting to download xdebug-2.4.0.tgz (264,832 bytes)
.....................done: 264,832 bytes

76 source files, building
running: phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory

grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory

grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory

Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:

Zend Module Api No:

Zend Extension Api No:

Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.
```

---

Help me find the way to solve that problem.

Comment: Could you try installing it via homebrew

Comment: No. I should to install BREW before?

Comment: If you get the `"cannot find autoconf"` error then you should first install `"autoconf"`. If you use `homebrew` then you can install autoconf with the following command: `brew install autoconf`

Answer (score 9):

XDebug is available by default. Just enable it by

1) `sudo nano /etc/php.ini` (or `sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini` first if the file doesn't yet exist)

2) Add these lines at the end (verify the path with ls `ls /usr/lib/php/extensions/`)

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so"
```

3) Restart apache using `sudo apachectl restart`

4) Verify by `php -m | grep xdebug`

Comment: I am trying to do the first step: Edit /etc/php.ini using VIW, but it creates new PHP.ini file. Is that normally?

Comment: `sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini`   Then edit it with `sudo nano /etc/php.ini`

Comment: I am trying but -    cp: /etc/php.ini.default: No such file or directory

Comment: Try `sudo cp /private/etc/php.ini.default /private/etc/php.ini`

Comment: cp: /private/etc/php.ini.default: No such file or directory... But I can found php.ini file in that catalogue.

Comment: I've found file PHP.ini and there is rows: zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.file_link_format="txmt://open?url=file://%f&line=%1"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000

Comment: Put a phpinfo and find your correct php.ini. Check section loaded config.

Comment: The string ls /usr/lib/php/extensions/ shows
no-debug-non-zts-20121212 . Is that normal?

Comment: Now I am trying wrote the string: sudo peel install xdebug -> and the result now is: downloading xdebug-2.4.0.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-2.4.0.tgz (264,832 bytes)
.....done: 264,832 bytes
76 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.
_________________________________________________________How to find autoconf ?

Comment: INSTALL AUTOCONF: curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz
tar xzf autoconf-latest.tar.gz           
cd autoconf-*           
./configure --prefix=/usr/local        
make         
sudo make install Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322742/php-autoconf-errors-on-mac-os-x-10-7-3-when-trying-to-install-pecl-extensions/12333230#12333230

Comment: Put a phpinfo and find your correct php.ini. Check section loaded config.

Answer (score 2):

Mike Chamberlain's excellent response almost got xdebug working with NetBeans using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.  Only two changes required: 
In step 2, after 
    zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so"
also add
    xdebug.remote_enable=1

This was necessary because the precompiled .so file has xdebug remote access disabled.  NetBeans and other tools need it to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging using xdebug i used the following steps

For installing php72 I installed using brew with the following command:

```
brew install homebrew/php/php72-xdebug
```

I added the following command to the bottom of the php.ini file:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php72-xdebug/2.6.0/xdebug.so
```

Note: if you need to search for a version of xdebug with brew use:

```
brew search xdebug
```

Comment: I am getting error - `Error: homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.`