# How can I install valgrind on MAC 10.7?

Tags: macos, valgrind, homebrew

I am running in the problems while I am installing valgrind. So, I uninstall everything and I am looking for good tutorial to follow. please help me out.

Sincerely
-salem

Comment: I download the zip folder. then I unzip it, ./configure. Once I typed make, this error came up make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a specific version and want something quick, have you tried installing it with homebrew?

[Install homebrew](http://brew.sh/) first, and then you can install valgrind with a specific [formula](http://brewformulas.org/Valgrind):

```
brew install valgrind
```

Comment: I did and this error appear on the command line screen           wireless1x-155-41-107-164:~ hdamin$ brew install valgrind
Error: Cannot write to /usr/local/Cellar
wireless1x-155-41-107-164:~ hdamin$

Comment: wireless1x-155-41-107-164:~ hdamin$ sudo brew install valgrind
Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install`
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.
wireless1x-155-41-107-164:~ hdamin$

Comment: Do a `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local` as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804169/installing-in-homebrew-errors

Comment: sudo brew install valgrind 
Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install`
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.
smp:~ hdamin$

Comment: That was a permission issue, now that the issue is fixed with `chown`, you can simply do `brew install valgrind` :)