# HomeBrew: Error- /usr/local/Cellar is not writable

Tags: macos, homebrew

When I run the following command in my terminal:

`usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

I get an error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar is not writable. You should change the
ownership and permissions of /usr/local/Cellar back to your
user account:
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar
```

Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force

I went through similar posts on S.O and all of them had the following commands as answer,so I ran the following commands in the terminal:

1. `sudo chown -R $tejas /usr/local/Cellar`
2. `sudo chown -R $tejas:admin /usr/local/Cellar`
3. `sudo chown -R $tejas /usr/local`
4. `sudo chown -R $tejas:admin /usr/local`

I ran the installation command after all above four command but it still gives me the error. Can someone please help me fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Did you just try `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar' ?

Comment: @Musen- Isn't that the first command I mentioned ?

Comment: I guess no? I mean literally `udo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar`, and do not replace whoami with anything.

Comment: I thought i was supposed to replace that with my account name :/

Comment: @Musen - It worked when I did `tejas$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/`

Comment: Both `$(whoami)` and `$USER` will be resolved to your user name.

Comment: Check out this post: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804169/installing-in-homebrew-errors). It solved my issue!

Comment: What if I need it to be available for several users on the same device?

Answer (score 19):

I had exactly same issue. I was trying to reset the permissions but some packages weren't able to install anyway. Re-installing the Homebrew solved this for me:

uninstall:
`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`

and then install it again:
`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Answer (score 19):

As said in the comments, just do (without any substitution):

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar
```

Answer (score 10):

Reset the permissions of /usr/local and Homebrew's caches to the current user:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local /Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue on MacOS when install GoAccess:

```
Error: /usr/local/Cellar is not writable. You should change the
ownership and permissions of /usr/local/Cellar back to your
user account:
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar
Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

I fixed it by run following command:

```
 sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:
This one might work on older operating systems, as it set permission to directory:

```
 sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/Cellar
```

Method 2. On newer system can't set permission on the directory istelf but there's a method to force adding permission to all children folders by using wilcard(asterisk) **'*'**, (of course a bit dangerous?).

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/Cellar/*
```

Method 3: Using prefix for brew (working from >=High Sierra)

```
sudo chown -R $USER $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help of @Lemaitre Cedric and @Rexcirus ... I fixed my issue.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local /Library/Caches/Homebrew
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar
```