# mac django error Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-mysql

I am trying to set up a django rest project on my mac. Whenever I run `python manage.py makemigrations` it shows: `Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?` error. However both of them are already installed.

Full stack trace:

```
    (VB_env) staff-207-213:VB_Backend_SCG nitishpatkar$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 30, in <module>
    'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
(VB_env) staff-207-213:VB_Backend_SCG nitishpatkar$ pip install mysqlclient
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in /Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.3.13)
(VB_env) staff-207-213:VB_Backend_SCG nitishpatkar$ pip install mysql-python
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-python in /Users/nitishpatkar/Development/Vision Backlog rewrite/VB_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.2.5)
(VB_env) staff-207-213:VB_Backend_SCG nitishpatkar$
```

Comment: Don't install both `mysql-python` and `mysqlclient`. Only install `mysqlclient`; it's newer and superior.

Comment: I did uninstall mysql-python but the error remains

Comment: @hansTheFranz yes I am inside my virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is

```
Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
```

i.e. the MySQL Python module can't be loaded as the OS can't find a symbol that should be in your OS's MySQL client libraries, likely caused by them being outdated.

This is referenced in e.g. this SO question: [Django - MySQLdb: Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299013/django-mysqldb-symbol-not-found-mysql-affected-rows)

How to actually solve this depends on the way you've installed those libraries in the first place (e.g. with `brew`?).

Comment: I installed MySQL by normally downloading and installing along with workbench. But while attempting to solve this problem, I also used Brew to install it. Otherwise mysqlclient I installed with pip

Comment: That sounds like a good way to get into conflicts :) I'd suggest getting rid of both installations of MySQL and then only installing it once with `brew`.

Comment: Okay let me try

Comment: So I uninstalled mysql also with brew, freshly installed it and with a fresh virtual environment tried to do migrations, but still threw same error.